# ALE says packages of my project don't exist

Tags: linux, plugin-ale, original-vim, filetype-java

I'm having this problem with **ale** where in `java` files, it sometimes gives an error message saying that some packages don't exist. However, I can run without any problems my projects once I compile them, and the files are there, so no idea why it's giving me this error.

### ALE error message

[image: Error message from ale]

```
error: package logic.list does not exist
```

### Project overview

[image: Output from tree (Overview of my project)]

```
src/
├── BuffyVampireSlayer.java
├── control
│   └── Controller.java
├── logic
│   ├── Game.java
│   ├── GameObjectBoard.java
│   ├── gameObjects
│   │   ├── Player.java
│   │   ├── Slayer.java
│   │   └── Vampire.java
│   ├── Level.java
│   └── list
│       ├── SlayerList.java
│       └── VampireList.java
├── utils
│   ├── Log.java
│   └── MyStringUtils.java
└── view
    └── GamePrinter.java

6 directories, 13 files
```

### ALE config section

```
let g:ale_fixers = {
      \  'java': ['google_java_format'],
      \ }
let g:ale_linters = {
      \  'cs':['syntax', 'semantic', 'issues'],
      \  'python': ['pylint'],
      \  'java': ['eclipselsp','javac']
      \ }
```

whole config [over here](https://github.com/ayhon/dotfiles/blob/main/vim/.vim/vimrc)

### Makefile I use to compile and run my project

```
run: compile printSep
    java -cp bin $(shell rgrep -l "public static void main" --exclude=Makefile | head -n 1 | sed -n "s#[^/]*/\(.*\)#\1#p" | sed "s/\.java//g") $(shell cat args)
printSep:
    @clear
    @printf '\e[33m--------\e[m\n'
compile:
    @clear
    @printf '\e[34mCompiling . . .\e[m\n'
    find . -regex ".*\.java" | xargs javac -d bin
```

I also used Eclipse to run it, which doesn't show any errors by the way.

### Other info

**OS:** Linux, Ubuntu 20.10
**Vim version:**
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Apr 15 2020 06:40:31)
Included patches: 1-2269

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I think the `javac` linter is like a single-file compile, so it doesn't work well for whole-projects. I would suggest either setting up one of the many java build tools (maven, gradle, ant, etc.?) or using a linter that works with projects (probably `eclipselsp` does)

Comment: That was the problem. I had to get rid of `javac` as a linter, and everything was working again. Thanks for the answer. Do you want to put as a separate answer so that I can check it as the solution, or do I do it myself? 
Anyways, thanks for everything.

Comment: I'm happy for you too; nothing wrong with self-answering. You can copy/quote the text from my comment, if you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Welcome to Vi and Vim! I think the `javac` linter is like a single-file compile, so it doesn't work well for whole-projects. I would suggest either setting up one of the many java build tools (maven, gradle, ant, etc.?) or using a linter that works with projects (probably `eclipselsp` does)

This was the answer, from [D. Ben Knoble](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/10604/d-ben-knoble). I had to get rid of the `javac` linter I had specified in my config.

```
let g:ale_linters = {
      \  'cs':['syntax', 'semantic', 'issues'],
      \  'python': ['pylint'],
      \  'java': ['eclipselsp']
      \ }
```